# Is it possible to handle props callback function of wrapped component by its wrapper div?

Tags: reactjs, function, properties, components

Let say I have component FilterItem as

```
export const FilterItem = (props: Props) => {
  const { value, action, checked, label, index } = props;
  return (
    <label
      className={classnames(styles.filterItemLabel)}
    >
      <Checkbox
        className={ classnames(styles.filterItemInput) }
        checked={ checked }
        onChange={ () => action(value, index) }
      />
      { label }
    </label>
  );
};
```

and Checkbox component as:

```
export const Checkbox = (props: Props) => {
  const { checked, onChange, className, disabled } = props;
  return (
    <span className={styles['checkboxWrapper']}>
      <input
        style={{ display: 'none' }}
        type="checkbox"
        checked={checked}
        onChange={onChange}
        disabled={disabled}
      />
    </span>
  );
};
```

My question, is it possible to write FilterItem component as: putting onChange function inside label as props. for my case, it still working. dont know the reason. is it specific to React.